# Connecting to a 3.3V can bus from linux laptop

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, can-bus

I am new to the CAN protocol. I need to connect to a 3.3V CAN network.
I can find USB powered CAN adapters but none for 3.3V. 
Can I use the 5V USB adapter anyway somehow?

Or will I have to bridge from laptop through USB to a microcontroller board with built-in CAN connectivity? But then I need to create my own USB-CAN bridging in the microcontroller, plus create my own USB driver for linux, right? Is this a good idea and how would it be for someone with a plenty of programming experience but very little on device drivers.

Do you have some experience or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [TI paper](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla337/slla337.pdf) 5V CAN is *"compatible and interoperable"* with 3.3V CAN.

> *3.3V  CAN  (Controller  Area  Network)  transceivers  offer  advantages  and  flexibility  with
>
>   respect to 5V CAN transceivers while being compatible and interoperable with each other.
>
>   ...
>
>   This  application  note  demonstrates  the interoperability 
>   of  3.3V  and  5V  CAN  transceivers  in  addition  to  explaining  the  theory  of operation.*

---

> Can I use the 5V USB adapter anyway somehow?

It's worth a try.

Also see https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/industrial_interface/f/142/t/230101 that reiterates the *"3V CAN Trasnceviers are fully interoperable with 5V CAN trasnceviers"* claim, and mentions the possible need for pull-down resistors and/or line-termination.

Comment: Wauw, thanks for tracing that PDF down for me. I will consider that an answer though I haven't tested it yet.